# Driver Ranking based on Aggressive Cluster

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I am clustering driver behavior data & found the most aggressive cluster where the means of all critical variables are high

when compared to other clusters. Now can I take the agressive cluster & find the proportion of drivers aggressive behavior that falls into the most aggressive cluster & use this proportion to rank among them ?

Comment: Question is unclear. What are you ranking?

Comment: @user2974951 I am raking the aggressiveness of drivers..I have few variables drivers who are overspeeding, breaking etc..

Comment: I don't understand. You have one cluster which you've identified as being composed of aggressive drivers, because they have the highest means. What do you want to do now on these drivers in this particular cluster? How will you rank them?

Comment: @ user2974951, I have clustered my drivers into 4 clusters depending on Silhouette chart (k=4 is optimal according to it) & apparantly 3rd cluster means were high for all the varables which I used for clustering . So I named that as most aggressive cluster. Now I take all my drivers and calculate what proportion of drivers behavior falls into the most aggressive cluster... accordingly I will rank them.   did i make sense to you.. please let me know

Comment: The proportion of drivers that belong in the aggresive cluster is trivial to compute, but how will you rank the individual drivers, what will you use to rank them?

Comment: @ user2974951, i used this code..   nrow(d[d$cluster == agressive_cluster_index,]) / nrow(d)

d is the dataframe which has original variables & their cluster assignment

agressive_cluster_index is most aggressive cluster

Comment: @ user2974951, i call it as aggressive ride rate

Comment: That code is for calculating the proportion of drivers which are in the aggressive cluster (if I understood correctly). OK, so where does ranking come in? How do you want to rank these drivers?

Comment: @ user2974951, i call it as aggressive ride rate (driver proportion in aggressive cluster).. & i am thinking to sort & rank that value

Comment: OK, aggressive ride rate = proportion of drivers in aggressive cluster. But what do you want to sort and rank exactly? What value? The proportion? How would that work?

Comment: user2974951, I want to sort & rank what proportion (Agg ride rate) of their behavior falls into the most aggressive cluster..accordingly i will rank them

Comment: @user2974951, if above doesnt make sense plz advise a best approach to rank these drivers aggressiveness

Comment: The proportion of aggresive drivers (Agg ride rate) is one value, for ex. say 30 % of drivers belong in the aggresive cluster. So how do you want to sort and rank this one value, 0.3? Are you trying to rank the drivers **inside** the aggresive clusters from most aggresive to least aggresive?

Comment: @user2974951 , okk i get it where you are going. I am taking about each driver proportionate behavior falling into that one aggressive cluster. So I will try to rank the drivers inside the aggressive cluster from most to least...

Comment: user2974951 , is this approach okay?

Comment: You mentioned `proportionate behavior in the cluster` so I am not sure what that means. Anyway, to rank the drivers you need a measure. There are many possible options here, the simplest is probably to estimate a mean for each driver based on all the variables, and then rank these means.

Comment: user2974951 , please forgive my jargon. I mean what percentage a drivers behavior falls into that one cluster (aggressive) & rank these percentages of drivers from most to least

Comment: Oh... so for every driver in your data set you want to calculate some sort of measure of how much they "belong" in the aggresive cluster? How "close" they are?

Comment: @user2974951 , yes you are right... plz advise if this is okay to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not suitable for your objective. But fear not, because you only need a small adjustment to get closer to your goal. Instead of using "hard" clustering algorithms (the kind that return hard labels), you need to use soft / fuzzy clustering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering which is a form of clustering in which each data point can belong to more than one cluster.

Additionally, membership grades are assigned to each of the data points (drivers). These membership grades indicate the degree to which data points belong to each cluster. Thus, points on the edge of a cluster, with lower membership grades, may be in the cluster to a lesser degree than points in the center of cluster.

**Note:** you could also do something similar with your current model, for ex. by estimating the "aggresive cluster" centroid, and then calculating how far each driver is from this centroid, but this is not as pretty.